# Comprensión de función javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

me gustaría saber si alguien me podría explicar como funciona esta función, en consola el resultado es 55 pero no entiendo como trabaja la función para llegar a dicho valor, gracias.

```
var suma = 0;
var i = 0;

function calculaSuma() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    suma += i;      
  }

  console.log(suma);
}

calculaSuma();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función esta trabajando de este modo, te lo dejo con una cantidad de digitos reducida pero es la misma idea que para tu ejercicio

Veo innecesario el uso de

`var i = 0`

Puesto que esta siendo redeclarada e inicializada dentro del `for` con un valor de 1

Ahora aquí el código

```js
    var suma = 0;
    
    function calculaSuma() {
      for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        suma += i;      
      }
    
      console.log(suma);
    }
    
    calculaSuma();
```

Ahora en consola esto nos mostrará **15**

Pero... ¿cómo se llegó a este resultado?, simple mira esta tabla que muestra las operaciones por cada iteración

```
/*
valor de i
i           1
0           = 0 + 1
1           = 1 + 1 
2           = 2 + 1
3           = 3 + 1
4           = 4 + 1
5           = 5 + 1

*/
```

Suma los valores de la izquierda en forma de columna, es decir hacia abajo y obtendrás el número 15 que la función nos devolvió

**EXPLICACIÓN**

1. Durante la primer iteración la `i` vale 1, entonces la operación `suma += i` se puede leer como 0 = 0 + 1
2. Ahora la nueva iteración tiene que la `i` vale 1, posterior hago otra vez 1 = 1 + 1
3. Ahora la nueva iteración tiene que la `i` vale 2, posterior hago otra vez 2 = 2 + 1
4. Ahora la nueva iteración tiene que la `i` vale 3, posterior hago otra vez 3 = 3 + 1
5. Ahora la nueva iteración tiene que la `i` vale 4, posterior hago otra vez 4 = 4 + 1
   Ahora la nueva iteración tiene que la `i` vale 5, posterior hago otra vez 5 = 5 + 1
6. Entonces al final sumo los valores que la `i` fue adquiriendo por cada iteración y obtengo 15

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ha sido de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez lo entiendas mejor si evitamos el for y te mostramos cual es la suma que realizan todas las iteraciones juntas.

En la variable "suma" (valga la redundancia) se suman todos los valores que vale "i" en cada iteración.

La variable "i" comienza con un valor de 1, y finaliza con un valor de 10.
Sabiendo que van a sumarse todos los números en ese rango, la suma de todos esos números serian:

suma = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10

Espero que se entienda bien.

Comment: gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder, ha sido de mucha ayuda.